# Creating OKEx orders using ccxt

Tags: python, api, ccxt

I'm trying to make program for creating SWAP orders in OKEx with StopLoss and TakeProfit in DEMO trading mode using ccxt module.
But I got error: `The current account mode does not support this API interface.` How I can solve it, and is there some examples of creating orders?
My attempt:

```py
params = {
        'tdMode': 'isolated',
        'tpOrdPx': '-1',
        'slOrdPx': '-1',
        'tpTriggerPx': take_profit,
        'slTriggerPx': stop_loss,
        'headers': {
            'x-simulated-trading': '1'
        }

    }
order = exchange.create_order(
        f"XRP/USDT:USDT", 'market', 'buy', summa, price, params=params)
```

Error code:

```py
File "/home/excl/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ccxt/base/exchange.py", line 561, in throw_exactly_matched_exception
    raise exact[string](message)
ccxt.base.errors.AccountNotEnabled: okx {"code":"1","data":[{"clOrdId":"*id*","ordId":"","sCode":"51010","sMsg":"The current account mode does not support this API interface. ","tag":""}],"msg":"Operation failed."}
```

Comment: Is there an error code as well as this would help identify the type of error? OKEx has 4 account modes namely simple, single-currency margin, multi-currency margin and portfolio margin modes. The different trading modes offer access to different instruments so my guess is that the trading mode you have selected for your account doesn't give you access to SWAP instruments. There's a guide here on how to change the account mode. https://www.okx.com/academy/en/guide-to-portfolio-margin-mode-on-okex

Comment: Yeah, that solved my problem.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by changing account mode from **simple** to **portfolio mode**.
https://www.okx.com/academy/en/guide-to-portfolio-margin-mode-on-okex